# nodejs Jest testing exec.stdout.on('data',data)

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nested

Trying to to test a function the incorporates the exec of child_process library.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process')

const randomFunc = () => { 
  const newSync = exec('some command to execute')
  newSync.stdout.on('data', data => {
   console.log(data.toString())
  })
}
```

testfile:

```
const {randomFunc} = require(randomFuncFile)
const { exec } = require('child_process')
jest.mock('child_process')

it('test', () => {
    const readStreamObject = {
      on: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function (event, handler) {
        handler('streaming ')
      })
    }
   exec.mockImplementation(data => ({stdout: readStreamObject})
   randomFunc()
   expect(exec.stdout.on).toHaveBeenCalled()
}
```

I'm getting

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

some tips would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the mock `stdout` returned by mocked `exec()` function via `exec.mock.results[0].value.stdout`, See [mockFn.mock.results](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresults)

`index.js`:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const randomFunc = () => {
  const newSync = exec('some command to execute');
  newSync.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
  });
};

module.exports = { randomFunc };
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const { randomFunc } = require('./');

jest.mock('child_process');

it('test', () => {
  const mStdout = {
    on: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function (event, handler) {
      handler('streaming');
    }),
  };
  exec.mockImplementation(() => ({ stdout: mStdout }));
  randomFunc();
  // expect(mStdout.on).toHaveBeenCalled();
  // or
  expect(exec.mock.results[0].value.stdout.on).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75036469/index.test.js (8.403 s)
  ✓ test (15 ms)

  console.log
    streaming

      at stackoverflow/75036469/index.js:6:13

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.016 s
```